# How to silence or suppress gfortran (or clang?) backend in conda?

Tags: r, fortran, clang, anaconda, conda

I have been working on building a very particular conda environment designed for `python` and `R` with cross-talk using `rpy2`.  The recipe I came up with that works to install the proper `R` packages is the following:

```
# install_main_environment.sh
now=$(date +"%T")
echo "Start Time: $now"

## Create Main Environment (OSX-64)
conda create -n python3 python=3 --yes
source activate python3

## Jupyter
conda install jupyterlab --yes

## R
conda install -c r r --yes
conda install -c r r-essentials --yes
conda install -c r rstudio --yes
conda install gfortran_osx-64 --yes
conda install -c anaconda clangxx_osx-64 --yes
conda install rpy2 --yes

## Install Python Packages
source ./install_python_packages.sh

## Install R Packages
RScript ./install_r_packages.r

# End
now=$(date +"%T")
echo "End Time: $now"
```

However, one of these lines has made the backend extremely verbose so everytime I source/deactivate an environment or install a package I get a very verbose backend.

**How can I suppress this or silence the extra text permanently?** In my bash profile when I activate my environment, I direct the stderr & stdout to /dev/null `source activate python3 > /dev/null 2>&1` but this is only a patch that is not universal.

This situation exists for both my work computer: 
`OSX 10.11.6 (El Capitan)` and my personal computer `OSX Sierra`.

Here is an example of the output I am referring to below:

```
jespinozlt-osx:~ jespinoz$ source activate python3

INFO: activate-gfortran_osx-64.sh made the following environmental changes:
+DEBUG_FFLAGS=-march=nocona -mtune=core2 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector -O2 -pipe -march=nocona -mtune=core2 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector -O2 -pipe -Og -g -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -fimplicit-none -fvar-tracking-assignments
+F95=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran
+FC=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran
+FFLAGS=-march=nocona -mtune=core2 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector -O2 -pipe
+FORTRANFLAGS=-march=nocona -mtune=core2 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector -O2 -pipe
+GFORTRAN=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran
INFO: activate_clang_osx-64.sh made the following environmental changes:
+AR=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar
+AS=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-as
+CC=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
+CFLAGS=-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe
+CHECKSYMS=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-checksyms
+CLANG=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
+CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-codesign_allocate
+CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk
+CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9
+DEBUG_CFLAGS=-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -Og -g -Wall -Wextra
+INDR=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-indr
+INSTALL_NAME_TOOL=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-install_name_tool
+LD=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ld
+LDFLAGS=-Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs
+LDFLAGS_LD=-pie -headerpad_max_install_names -dead_strip_dylibs
+LIBTOOL=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-libtool
+LIPO=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-lipo
+NM=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-nm
+NMEDIT=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-nmedit
+OTOOL=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-otool
+PAGESTUFF=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-pagestuff
+RANLIB=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ranlib
+REDO_PREBINDING=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-redo_prebinding
+SEGEDIT=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-segedit
+SEG_ADDR_TABLE=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-seg_addr_table
+SEG_HACK=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-seg_hack
+SIZE=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-size
+STRINGS=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-strings
+STRIP=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-strip
+_PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME=_sysconfigdata_x86_64_apple_darwin13_4_0
INFO: activate_clangxx_osx-64.sh made the following environmental changes:
+CLANGXX=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++
+CXX=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++
+CXXFLAGS=-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++14 -fmessage-length=0
+DEBUG_CXXFLAGS=-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++14 -fmessage-length=0 -Og -g -Wall -Wextra
```

### Below are links to `pastebin` for requested outputs/scripts:

As suggested by  Tarun Lalwani in comments:

#### Stdout

[bash -xlc "source activate python3" 1> activate_output.o](https://pastebin.com/B5uqKJXf)

#### Stderr

[bash -xlc "source activate python3" 2> activate_output.e](https://pastebin.com/ndzzJsm7)

Scripts requested by Trishansh Bhardwaj and Tarun Lalwani in comments:

#### Script

[Associated scripts](https://pastebin.com/X50suU2b)

Comment: [The solution](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall)

Comment: Do you mean uninstall?

Comment: Please share contents of `activate' file?

Comment: Please run it like below `bash -xlc "source activate python3"` Then you can see which command is actually causing the verbose output. Once you find the command, you can just make it shut up

Comment: @TarunLalwani thanks for response.  I've posted the `stdout` and `stderr` to pastebin above in the question.

Comment: @TrishanshBhardwaj, how can I actually access the `activate` script?

Comment: Can you give a combined output, I don't need separate ones. Also do `which activate` and the get the path and do a `cat <path>` from which

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've posted the script above on pastebin.

Comment: And a single output for `bash -xlc "source activate python3"`?

Comment: @TarunLalwani https://pastebin.com/M3zZ4gBt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169705/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-o-rka).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the below folders

```
/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/python3/etc/conda
```

There is a `activate.d` and `deactivate.d` folder inside the same, which gets executed, during `activate` and `deactivate`

These files have below code section

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "ERROR: $(_get_sourced_filename) failed, see above for details"
else
  if [ -f /tmp/new-env-$$.txt ]; then
    rm -f /tmp/new-env-$$.txt || true
  fi
  env > /tmp/new-env-$$.txt

  echo "INFO: $(_get_sourced_filename) made the following environmental changes:"
  diff -U 0 -rN /tmp/old-env-$$.txt /tmp/new-env-$$.txt | tail -n +4 | grep "^-.*\|^+.*" | grep -v "CONDA_BACKUP_" | sort
fi
rm -f /tmp/old-env-$$.txt /tmp/new-env-$$.txt || true
```

You need to comment these to disable the verbose output. This code basically saves current `env` to a file and then run the activation code, capture `env` again and print the diff