# clang backend when I start the terminal

Tags: anaconda, clang, darwin

I am not sure how much the
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995804/how-to-silence-or-suppress-gfortran-or-clang-backend-in-conda) helps. I have to see the list of these messages upon opening the terminal. It came with installing clang for the sake of pystan I believe.

I would very much like to denoise the following, but I've not got a good clue. Appreciate any input, thanks.

```
INFO: activate_clang_osx-64.sh made the following environmental changes:
+AR=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar
+AS=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-as
+CC=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
+CFLAGS=-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe
+CHECKSYMS=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-checksyms
+CLANG=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
+CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-codesign_allocate
+CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk
+CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9
+DEBUG_CFLAGS=-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -Og -g -Wall -Wextra
+HOST=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
+INDR=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-indr
+INSTALL_NAME_TOOL=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-install_name_tool
+LD=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ld
+LDFLAGS=-Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs
+LDFLAGS_LD=-pie -headerpad_max_install_names -dead_strip_dylibs
+LIBTOOL=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-libtool
+LIPO=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-lipo
+NM=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-nm
+NMEDIT=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-nmedit
+OTOOL=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-otool
+PAGESTUFF=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-pagestuff
+RANLIB=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ranlib
+REDO_PREBINDING=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-redo_prebinding
+SEGEDIT=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-segedit
+SEG_ADDR_TABLE=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-seg_addr_table
+SEG_HACK=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-seg_hack
+SIZE=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-size
+STRINGS=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-strings
+STRIP=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-strip
+_PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME=_sysconfigdata_x86_64_apple_darwin13_4_0
INFO: activate_clangxx_osx-64.sh made the following environmental changes:
+CLANGXX=//anaconda/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++
+CXX=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++
+CXXFLAGS=-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++14 -fmessage-length=0
+DEBUG_CXXFLAGS=-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++14 -fmessage-length=0 -Og -g -Wall -Wextra
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I wish not to see these when I open a terminal window every time.. as I believe it is possible.

Comment: In that case (1) wrong website, try https://superuser.com/ (2) You probably want to look at your `~/.bashrc` file, an installer has presumably added something to the end of it.

Comment: which I did and commented out all the unnecessity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed this by the link, but it remains murky which of the versions btw clangxx_osx-64-4.0.1-h22b1bf0_8 vs. clangxx_osx-64-4.0.1-h22b1bf0_11 caused it. It seemed more likely that the recent version should be the reason for it, but I actually got lucky by commenting out the lines that were similarly mentioned in the link from the older version..